# What is a postpositional enclitic?

Tags: terminology, linguistics

What is a post positional enclitic? I don't know anything about it, but I think it is a part of english grammar.

Comment: Probly just another term for a post-clitic, like the English possessive -_' s_ marker, which goes at the end of a noun phrase, instead of inflecting a noun like a case marker. _The Queen of England's hat_, not **the Queen's of England hat*.

Comment: Have you looked up the meaning of _postpositional_ and _enclitic_? What remains unclear to you after doing so? Postpositional enclitics are not “a part of English grammar” as such; they're just enclitics that are postpositional, which is a very common thing to have in many, many languages.

Comment: One might call -n't in couldn't a postpositional enclitic,  even if I have never in my life needed such a term for a simple contraction. Some people have the idea they explain language by inventing useless academic terms which take an hour to explain them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Enclitic**

> a word pronounced with so little emphasis that it is shortened and forms part of the preceding word, for example n't in can't.

**Post-position**

> a word or morpheme placed after the word it governs, for example -ward in homeward.

Source: Oxford Dictionaries

Clubbing these definitions together, a post-positional enclitic is a word or a morpheme(an indivisible unit like -ing, -ward) that follows another word and is pronounced with so little emphasis that people prefer to shorten it and make it a part of the previous word itself. That shortened form is the enclitic.

For ex: can not==> can't
(The apostrophe stands for the missing *no* in can *no*t)

The clitic form(or post positional enclitic) of not in this case is *n't*.

he will==> he'll

The clitic form(or post positional enclitic) of will in this case is *'ll*.

For more information on this topic, check [this](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/Clitic.htm) out.